# 960 css `grid_9 align_right` not aligning to the right

Tags: css, 960.gs

If you [download the 960.css system](http://github.com/nathansmith/960-Grid-System/zipball/master) and unzip it, you will find some demo files in the `code` directory.

If you rip out all the demo code and create [the following simple HTML file](https://github.com/metaperl/vcpaste/blob/master/paste/2011-10-05-15-17-58/simple.html),
you will note that the div with class instructions to take up 9 columns and align to the right does NOT align to the right, but to the left.

I LOVE 960.css - THANK YOU O GREAT AUTHOR. However, I would like to know why this one thing which I think should work is not working.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `align_right` does not ship with 960.gs, so you have to add it manually:

```
.align_right {
 text-align: right;
}
```